# Memory leak on allocating and releasing an NSArray

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsarray

I'm getting a reported memory leak from Instruments on the following code:

```
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Amount (oz):", @"Amount (ml):", @"Supplement:", nil];
self.fieldLabels = array;
[array release];
```

fieldLabels is an iVar, declared as:

```
 NSArray *fieldLabels;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *fieldLabels;
```

Instruments reports the following:

```
#   Category    Event Type  Timestamp   RefCt   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   __NSArrayI  Malloc  00:16.513.592   1   0x660bb40   32  InfantCare  -[Supplemental_Amount viewDidLoad]
1   __NSArrayI  Retain  00:16.513.595   2   0x660bb40   0   InfantCare  -[Supplemental_Amount setFieldLabels:]
2   __NSArrayI  Release 00:16.513.595   1   0x660bb40   0   InfantCare  -[Supplemental_Amount viewDidLoad]
```

I then changed the code so instead of:

```
self.fieldLabels = array;
```

I put:

```
[self setFieldLabels:array];
```

No more leak (supposedly!).  Why would this be?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both syntax are identical. Given the fact that you have declared your `fieldLabels` property with a retain attribute the reference count of your array after your call to `setFieldLabels` (which is called when you write: `self.fieldLabels = array`) is 1 which is what you would expect. Indeed given the sequence of calls in your code the following is happening:

1. `NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Amount (oz):", @"Amount (ml):", @"Supplement:", nil];` This sets the refCount of the memory allocated to 1
2. `self.fieldLabels = array;` Will retain the array, release whatever was previously retained by `fieldLabels` and assign `fieldLabels` to the retained array. At this stage the retain count of array is 2 (1 from init, 1 from the property assignment).
3. `[array release];` Brings the retain count back to 1 for the array which is what you want.

Comment: That's what I thought...however, why is Instruments reporting that as a memory leak?

Comment: Maybe the leak happens later when the object holding the `fieldLabels` is unloaded. Are you releasing `fieldLabels` everywhere you should?